# How do Maps work in Ecmascript 6 with Object keys?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I have been examining the spec for the upcoming Map data structure in ES6. It's supposed to be great because anything can be a key in a Map, not just strings, but when I tried it with a few object examples, I could not retrieve the values I had inserted into the Map.

```
  var _projects = new Map();
  _projects.set({}, [...]);
  _projects.set({page: 2}, [...]);



  _projects.has({page:2})
  false
```

Then I saw this in the [Mozilla developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) site:

> Key equality is based on the "same-value" algorithm: NaN is considered
>   the same as NaN (even though NaN !== NaN) and all other values are
>   considered equal according to the semantics of the === operator.

If this is the case, then what are my options if I want to retrieve the values for an object based on its value, rather than its identity?

Comment: Objects are compared by identity, not by value.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that `{x:5} !== {x:5}` is true because they are two different objects.

You have to reference them.

Meaning you can't just `_projects.has({x:5})` because that's a new object.

You have to do the following:

```
var _projects = new Map();
var obj = {x:5};
_projects.set(obj, [1,2]);

_projects.has(obj) //true;
```

Comment: But if you updated the value of `obj.x` to 6, this still returns true. That doesn't make sense to me. Intuitively, I can understand that when you change `obj`, the key of `_projects` is also updated, but it just doesn't feel right.

Comment: why doesn't it feel right. If you `obj.x++` which is 6 the object is also updated in the map because that is the same object? what's not to get, or what is it your trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies to Map and Set, however as ES6 builtins they may be subclassable github.com/lukehoban/es6features#subclassable-built-ins - there was a post a while ago on subclassing these. There are a whole shed load of other problems though if you are going to identify objects by value.

Comment: I agree with @picardo , in java you can use objects as keys in HashMaps by making objects immutable.You can then retrieve them by changing the default equality, which can be done overriding the 'equals' method. Did someone found any solution to do that in Javascript?